# Returning the 3-dimensional vector from a skew symmetric matrix

Tags: functions, matrix, function-construction, vector

I'm trying to write a function that takes in a skew symmetric matrix and returns the corresponding vector. When I write the following code, it works when I leave it as variables, but it does not work when I plug in numbers. Any help would be appreciated.

```
skewToq[{{0, -q3_, q2_}, {q3_, 0, -q1_}, {-q2_, q1_, 0}}] := {q1, q2, q3};
skewToq[{{0, -q3, q2}, {q3, 0, -q1}, {-q2, q1, 0}}]
{q1, q2, q3}
```

Now, when I plug in an actual skew-symmetric matrix, the function does not work...

```
skewToq[{{0, -3, 2}, {3, 0, -1}, {-2, 1, 0}}]
skewToq[{{0, -3, 2}, {3, 0, -1}, {-2, 1, 0}}]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

There is a built-in function [`HodgeDual`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HodgeDual.html)

```
Normal@HodgeDual[{{0, -3, 2}, {3, 0, -1}, {-2, 1, 0}}]
(* {-1, -2, -3} *)

Normal@HodgeDual[{-1, -2, -3}]
(* {{0, -3, 2}, {3, 0, -1}, {-2, 1, 0}} *)
```

Comment: ... of course there's a built-in.  Should have known.

Answer (score 3):

As belisarius implies, Mathematica's pattern matcher matches literal expressions and not mathematical equalities.

Here's another implementation:

```
skewToq[M_] :=  If[
    And[Dimensions[M] == {3, 3}, M == -Transpose[M]], 
    {M[[3, 2]], M[[1, 3]], M[[2, 1]]}
    ]
skewToq[{{0, -q3, q2}, {q3, 0, -q1}, {-q2, q1, 0}}]
(* {q1, q2, q3} *)
skewToq[{{0, -3, 2}, {3, 0, -1}, {-2, 1, 0}}]
(* {1, 2, 3} *)
```

Comment: Thanks, this returns the correct answer. The Normal@HodgeDual function is not giving me the correct vector representation

Answer (score 1):

Skewfunction[{q1_,q2_,q3_}]:=MatrixForm[{{0,-q3,q2},{q3,0,-q1},{-q2,q1,0}}];

Skewfunction[{a,b,c}]

(0  -c  b
c   0   -a
-b  a   0)

Answer (score 0):

```
ClearAll[sToq]

sToq[M_] /; AntisymmetricMatrixQ[M] := {M[[3, 2]], M[[1, 3]], M[[2, 1]]}

sToq[{{0, -q3, q2}, {q3, 0, -q1}, {-q2, q1, 0}}]
```

> ```
>  {q1, q2, q3}
> ```

```
sToq[{{0, -3, 2}, {3, 0, -1}, {-2, 1, 0}}]
```

> ```
>  {1, 2, 3}
> ```

```
sToq[{{0, 3, 2}, {3, 0, -1}, {-2, 1, 0}}]
```

> ```
>  sToq[{{0, 3, 2}, {3, 0, -1}, {-2, 1, 0}}]
> ```